# Javascript alternative to Confirm() dialog, not async

Tags: javascript

We are trying to improve the look of our **Confirm** JS dialogs, there are some good options like http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/ or this https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/utils/ui/dialog/Methods/

the problem is that all of them are **async** while the Javascript native confirm is **sync**, it is important because **it stops the flow until it gets an input from the user**.

It is not easy to change the native confirm by an async one because there is a lot of code to change and many possibilities to break something.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no custom "confirm" available that halts the execution of code. Only the native one does that. You'll have to either stick with the native one, or refactor your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No alternative for confirm(), confirm is only one.

**You can make yours if you want.**

alert() and prompt() is usually paired with confirm.